# Retrieve values and types of all SPFields in SharePoint object

Tags: c#, sharepoint

Say I have run a query with SPQuery, and now I want to extract to a string all values and types contained inside the resulting object. How can I achieve this? I don't seem to get how values are retrieved in SharePoint

```
string dummyString="";
SPListItemCollection ic=myList.GetItems(myQuery);
foreach(SPListItem li in ic){
    foreach(SPItem i in li){
        foreach(SPField f in i){
            dummyString=dummyString+ "\n" + "Value: " +f.???.ToString() +"; type: " + f.????.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `SPField` instance represents *metadata*, not the actual value of a field in a `SPListItem` instance. The `Item[]` indexer on `SPListItem` allows access to values. If you don't know the IDs or names of fields, you can use `SPField` instances to retrieve them, like this:

```
foreach (SPListItem item in collection)
{
    foreach (SPField field in item.Fields)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(item[field.Id].ToString());
    }
}
```